# Multi Select Button Tag Cloud with jQuery Mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

Trying to create a jQuery Mobile screen that has a bunch of inline buttons that wrap to form a tag cloud.  Need to be able to select multiple buttons.  Tried using inline buttons (but can't figure out how to have them multi-selectable).  Tried using horizontal grouped mini checkboxes, but they are connected to each other (and I need some spacing between the buttons).

Any ideas welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably utilize classes on the buttons to indicate what's selected and use css to indicate active/selected state then using jQuery depending on how the Tag functions have selected items be appended to the param string or picked up by your filter to enable multi-select.
How is your tag filtering done? You can either add a search button below the cloud so it only runs when all selections are made, or on each select append the selection to the filter.